# structuremap configuration asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I have a problem with MVC4 StructureMap configuration, when I run the project the compiler fires this error

```
 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Mace_CrmSystem.Controllers.HomeController
```

this is my code

global.aspx code

```
namespace Mace_CrmSystem
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Oqla", "Oqla", new { controller = "Home", action = "index" });
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyCustomeFactory());
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<string>().Use<string>());

         }
    }


}
```

MycustomeFactory class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using StructureMap;
namespace Mace_CrmSystem
{
    public class MyCustomeFactory : System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory
    {

        protected override System.Web.Mvc.IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return  StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as System.Web.Mvc.IController;

        }
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mace_CrmSystem.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public HomeController(string parameter)
        {
            TempData["Hi"] = "Hi";
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

    }

    public class logger
    {
        public void log()
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

what I noticed that when I add a parameter of type object like

```
 public HomeController(logger parameter)
```

instead of

```
 public HomeController(string parameter)
```

and

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<logger>().Use<logger>());
```

instead of

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.For<string>().Use<string>());
```

it works probably but with the string parameter it does not work .

so please couold anyone explain that for me.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of StructureMap (and someone please correct me if I'm wrong) the reason you're seeing the behaviour that you're seeing is because StructureMap will use the longest constructor by default and attempt to fill in the parameters with the default instance registered with StructureMap.

In your instance you're not providing a default instance of string so StructureMap doesn't know how to resolve it.

If you wish to do what you're trying to do then your best bet is to look at creating a custom convention ([see this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077293/structuremap3-how-to-configure-constructor-string-injection-for-all-types)), however these do rely on knowing the name of the property your constructor is expecting.

Generally though, when dealing with strings your best bet is to move the string to an intermediate type and inject that instead.